# OS X 10.8.3 shows incorrect size of partition

Tags: macos, partitioning, osx-mountain-lion

I have a MacBook Air 3,2. A while ago I installed Ubuntu using rEFIt and everything worked fine. But after some time I wanted to develop an iPhone app and I needed to upgrade my OS X to Mountain Lion due to Xcode.

I did not find out how to upgrade only the partition with Mac OS X, so I deleted all the Ubuntu-related partitions. I saved everything on Time Machine, upgraded OS X, put everything back from Time Machine and started coding.

Now I have only one partition – my problem is that the size taken by my volume on this partition is not correct. When I click on the disk and select partition, the blue area is said to be 88.67. But when I click the volume, it says that it only takes 78.4 GB.

Where are the missing 10 or so GB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's a combination of two things:

First, the blue region in Disk Utility's Partition tab isn't just the space taken up by files, it also includes some protective overhead that Disk Utility adds in automatically. Disk Utility will not let you shrink the partition until it has no space left, and the blue region takes this into account.

Second, some of your disk space may be taken up by [Time Machine local snapshots](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4878); Disk Utility and the Finder both treat the space they take up as free (because it'll be freed on demand), but it's technically in use, and I'm pretty sure it's included in Disk Utility's blue region.

If you want to see how much space they're taking up, use System Information (from the Apple Menu choose *About This Mac*, then click *More Info*, then the *Storage* tab, then look for a purple *Backups* section in the usage graph).

Answer (score 1):

It is probably the recovery partition that Mac OSX automatically creates. For more details see [apple.com](http://www.apple.com/osx/recovery/)